# Having Trouble Pulling a Value with Quotes from SQL Server Table in C#

Tags: c#, sql, c#-4.0, ssis, sqldatareader

I'm building a dynamic SSIS package using C# EzAPI and I want to store the Meta Data Mapping in a SQL Server Table.

I am having trouble pulling in the delimiter ("\t" for example) and EOL Characters ("\r\n") from a table into C#.

[image: SQL Table]

Here is the line of code that I am trying to get to work:

```
flatFileColumn.ColumnDelimiter = columns.GetUpperBound(0) == 
   Array.IndexOf(columns, column) ? SqlValuesDictionary["EndOfLineChar"] : SqlValuesDictionary["Delimiter"];
```

These dictionary values are strings I retrieved from a SQL Server Data Reader like this: `SqlValuesDictionary["Delimiter"] = DataReader["Delimiter"].ToString()`where delimiter is the column containing `"\t"`.

So the problem is when I read in this value from SQL Server, it appears to be escaping every quote and `\` and causing the value to get changed when I really want a literal "\t" for tab delimiter.

So When I change the code to read:

```
flatFileColumn.ColumnDelimiter = columns.GetUpperBound(0) == 
       Array.IndexOf(columns, column) ? "\r\n" : "\t";
```

It works fine.

The debugger is not helping much because it appears to be displaying escapes that aren't even there so trying to replace the extra `\s` does nothing.

In the debugger the value of SqlValuesDictionary["Delimiter"] appears as `"\"\\t\""` when the literal table value is `"\t"`. When I change the table values to `\t` debugger shows it as `"\\t"` and it still fails.

[image: Debugger]

Can anyone point me a better direction for how to resolve this? Perhaps I am going about it the wrong way. For those concerned with SQL Injection, these tables will be strictly controlled by internal employees only.

To Clarify and Summarize: What value can I put in a SQL table and how do I retrieve it in C# to be the equivalent of `var tab = "\t"`

Comment: What is the exact problem you're having? And what is `SqlValuesDictionary`?

Comment: C# interprets "\t" correctly as a tab and I want to be able to read that from a table. It's just a <string,string> for storing the data from a sql table.

Comment: C# interprets `\t` as a tab only in a string literal. There's nothing special about that sequence when it comes from a database.

Comment: Somehow reading the value from the database in a datareader makes it different than me literally typing it. That is the problem. When I type "\t" in C# it interprets it as the symbol for tab and works fine. When I pull in the nvarchar value \t or "\t" from the database with a datareader and convert to string, it interprets it as the literal string with escapes "\\t" or \"\\t\" which is not what I want.

Comment: The string doesn't actually _have_ escapes. It's just the string. Think about it - why would data read from the outside follow the same syntax rules as string literals in the C# language? Why wouldn't it follow the rules of VB.NET, or Java? Or even T-SQL? The fact is that data is just data.

Comment: Well, when I type string tab = "\t"; its just the string also, but C# is smart enough to understand I want the symbol for tab instead of the string literal "\t"; I guess I thought it would understand the same value from the database somehow, but that's clearly not the case. The fix was just inserting char(9) into the database instead of literal string \t.

Comment: No, it's not "just the string". It is interpreted by the compiler. External data is not interpreted by the compiler. That would make no sense, as different compilers would interpret it differently. Compile time and run time are two different things (which is why they have two different names).

Comment: Your comments are helpful, thank you. It was just a lack of understanding thinking that my C# `string tab = "\t";` could be replaced from the database with `string tab = functionThatSaysThisIsNotLiterallyAString("\\t");` or something like that which probably doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same problem.

Found two reasonable  ways to get around it:

A: Insert an actual `<cr><lf>` in the table:

```
UPDATE [EzAPI_Meta].[ezapi].[FlatFile]
   SET [RowDelimiter] = CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)

I think it's a problem that you can't see those characters when you look at the table.
```

B: So I endeed up with replacing the characters in my C# code:

```
RowDelimiter.Replace("\\r\\n", "\r\n").Replace("{CR}{LF}", "\r\n");

With this one you can enter "\r\n" or "{CR}{LF}" as plain text in your table
```